# Get a same path downloaded , file but can't open the file

Tags: swift, pdf, path

so,i have collection view and can download pdf file from that, i get the path like this `file:///Users/community/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F9AB746D-20C3-4333-AE70-2840538F4AED/data/Containers/Data/Application/977E843C-15D6-4169-9980-1EBD5CBE3660/Library/Caches/81791.pdf` it can view the file, but when i use path like this

```
Optional(file:///Users/crocodic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F9AB746D-20C3-4333-AE70-2840538F4AED/data/Contai ... 358.pdf) it can't view the file.
```

What should i do? in swift

here's my code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let vc:RedirectMagazineViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NEXT") as! RedirectMagazineViewController
if (self.localPathArray.count > indexPath.row) {
   vc.receiveData = NSURL(string: databaseResult[0].pathDatabase)! // here i pass the path downloaded file to next view controller
}
   vc.receiveTitle = titleMagazine[indexPath.item]       
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and on my second view controller to view pdf file

```
var path = ""
var receiveData: NSURL!
var receiveTitle: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    self.title = receiveTitle
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: receiveData))
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have try, it is look like you are using optional wrapping with your path var.

Comment: i edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can load your pdf to an UIWebView by downloading it in your document directory.

```
if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("81791", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
            let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width-40,self.view.frame.size.height-40))
            webView.loadRequest(request)
            self.view.addSubview(webView)
        }
```